# R: Using Mapply to avoid loop

Tags: r

I have following code which I perform with for loop to generate a 3D array "newarr".

```
n1<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
n2<-c(3,4,5,6,7)
n3<- c(4,5,6,7,8)

afun <- function(y,p,q,r){
              calc=1/(1+(((y-p)/q)^(2*r)))
              return(calc)
        }

newarr<- array(dim = c(4,5,5))
Amat<-matrix(data=c(1:10,NA,NA,NA,NA,15:20),nrow = 4,ncol = 5)
Bmat<-matrix(data=c(1:6,NA,NA,NA,NA,11:20),nrow = 4,ncol = 5)
Qmat<- +(!is.na(Amat) & !is.na(Bmat))

for(i in 1:5){
     res<-afun(Amat,n1[i],n2[i],n3[i])
     newarr[,,i]<- res 
}
```

I want to use `Mapply` (or any apply function) instead of `for` loop. 
    arr2 <-  array((mapply(function(x,y,n1,n2,n3) if(x==1) afun(y,n1,n2,n3) else 0,Qmat,Amat,n1,n2,n3)),c(4,5,5))

The following code seems to help but without condition as described further:
    newarr <- array(mapply(afun, n1,n2,n3, MoreArgs = list(y=Amat)), c(4,5,5))

I want to include a condition by using Qmat (a 4x5 matrix with 0 and 1), so that when '0' is observed, no operation should be performed and return '0'value to fill matrix. For 1s in Qmat, perform 'afun' function and return the value to "newarr" to form a 3D matrix.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What is the logic of you part with `Qmat`? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: I will provide some precise information.  Amat is a matrix as shown below:                                                 
Amat<-matrix(data=c(1:10,NA,NA,NA,NA,15:20),nrow = 4,ncol = 5)                  Bmat<-matrix(data=c(1:6,NA,NA,NA,NA,11:20),nrow = 4,ncol = 5)    
 Qmat <- +(!is.na(Amat) & !is.na(Bmat)).  Qmat will generate a matrix of 4 x 5 with values 0 and 1. I want to perform evaluation of 'newarr' value whenever Qmat corresponds to 1. Hope it explains.

Comment: Let us see if I got the point: for every 1 in Qmat you get the 3D-array `newarr` (is it always the same 3D-array?) and for every 0 in Qmat you want to get 0 (or a 3-dimenional array in the same form as `newarr` with values 0 ?). How should the result look like, a 5-dimensional array? Please put your clarifications about the logic in your question, i.e. edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44115125/edit

Comment: For every 0 in Qmat I do not want to perform any operation and return zero for all cells of the matrix. Just for all 1s in Qmat, I want to generate newarr. The result should be a 3D array with (4 x5) x 5 times because Amat is of size 4x5 and n1,n2 and n3 are vectors of size 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the desired result:

```
newarr <- array(mapply(afun, n1,n2,n3, MoreArgs = list(y=Amat)), c(4,5,5))
```

this is using the implicit SIMPLIFY=TRUE of mapply(). With SIMPLIFY=TRUE each result is reduced to a vector. (a matrix is a vector with a dimension attribute)
Another variant is

```
array(unlist(mapply(afun, n1,n2,n3, MoreArgs = list(y=Amat), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)), c(4,5,5))
```

here you will get a list of matrices as result from mapply(). You have to unlist.

Comment: Thanks a lot... !! But I have a condition to add... The 'afun' should work when values in a matrix is 1. lets consider below matrix with 1 and 0.  Could you please help me in this as well..                   
 Qmat<-matrix(c(rep(1),0,0,0,0),nrow = 4,ncol = 5)....